# Error starting monerod

Tags: monerod, mining, monerod-commands

When running *./monerod --offline* I get the following output. Running on Windows 10 Pro in Microsoft Azure using MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit

The error messages are in bold.

monerod does not run.

> 2018-07-04 09:59:46.958 8496    INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/main.cpp:279 Monero '  Lithium Luna'
>   (v0.12.1.0-master-aa6850c7)
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:46.958 8496    INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/protocol.h:53       I  nitializing cryptonote protocol...
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:46.958 8496    INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/protocol.h:58       C  ryptonote protocol initialized OK
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:46.958 8496    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63
>   Initiali  zing p2p server...
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:47.474 8496    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68
>   p2p serv  er initialized OK
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.162 8496    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63
>   Initiali  zing core RPC server...
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.162 8496    INFO    global 
>   contrib/epee/include/net/http_se  rver_impl_base.h:76     Binding on
>   127.0.0.1:18081
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.162 8496    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:69
>   core RPC   server initialized OK on port: 18081
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.162 8496    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:86
>   Initiali  zing core...
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.162 8496    INFO    global 
>   src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_c  ore.cpp:427     Loading blockchain
>   from folder C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb ...
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.366 8496    INFO    global 
>   src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_c  ore.cpp:525     Loading checkpoints
>   2018-07-04 09:59:48.366 8496    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:92
>   Core ini  tialized OK
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.366 8496    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:74
>   Starting   core RPC server...
>
> 2018-07-04 09:59:48.366 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/rpc.h:79    c  ore RPC server started ok
>
> **2018-07-04 09:59:48.380 [SRV_MAIN]      ERROR   default src/rpc/zmq_server.cpp:1  12      Error creating ZMQ Socket: Address in use**
>
> **2018-07-04 09:59:48.380 [SRV_MAIN]      ERROR   daemon 
>   src/daemon/daemon.cpp:16  2       Failed to add TCP Socket
>   (127.0.0.1:18082) to ZMQ RPC Server**
>
> 2018-07-04 10:00:09.552 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/rpc.h:84    S  topping core RPC server...
>
> 2018-07-04 10:00:09.552 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/rpc.h:96    D  einitializing core RPC server...
>
> 2018-07-04 10:00:09.552 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/p2p.h:90    D  einitializing p2p...
>
> 2018-07-04 10:00:13.600 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/core.h:103  D  einitializing core...
>
> 2018-07-04 10:00:13.711 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/protocol.h:75  Stopping cryptonote protocol...
>
> 2018-07-04 10:00:13.711 [SRV_MAIN]      INFO    global 
>   src/daemon/protocol.h:79
>
> **Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully**

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by restarting the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Another process is bound to port 18082, which monerod uses for its 0MQ RPC server. That other process has to let go of that port (possibly by being stopped) before monerod can use it. Alternatively, you can tell monerod to use another port using `--zmq-rpc-bind-port X`, replacing X with your chosen port.

Comment: any ideas why a another process be bound to that port?

Comment: I am not familiar with your particular computer.